# Java.Lang. UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java

Phone crashed while playing Merge Dragons.  Rebooted and cleared cache.  BUT game was zipped..Tried unzippping and this came up instead, java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(DexPathList((zip file"/data/app/com.gramgames.mergedragons-M4x4KpkcoePzRyQu1DMHMQ==/base.apk"),nativeLibraryDirectories=(/data/app/com.gramgames.mergedragons-M4x4KpkcoePzRyQu1DMHMQ==/lib/arm,?system/lib,/vendor/lib)))couldn't find "libmain.so"
Can this be fixed, and if so how?

Comment: Please provide more details, which phone operating system, and the error stack trace.

Comment: Is this a programming problem? Or do you try to fix your phone?

Comment: My phone is a samsung galaxy J2 core Model SM-J260Y android version 8.1.0. I do not know where to find the error stack trace.

Comment: I did not try to fix my phone. All I did wad empty cache and then tried to get it out of the zip file it had somehow been put in.